# How to get Azure subscription ID when using AzureRM service connection?

Tags: azure-devops

I have a custom ADO task with standard AzureRM service endpoint in the task.json:

```
"name": ConnectedServiceName",
"type": "connectedService:AzureRM"
```

This allows users to select an Azure subscription. However, I need to pass the subscription ID to a backend script and I can't see how this is exposed? `$(ConnectedServiceName)` is the id of the connected service, not the subscription ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the powershell script to get the Azure subscription ID from the AzureRM service connection.

Here is an example:

File：

```
Ps_modules (VstsTaskSdk)

Test.ps1

Icon.png

Task.json
```

Test.ps1

In the task (the powershell script) you get this input via

```
$ConnectedServiceName = Get-VstsInput -Name ConnectedServiceName -Require
```

Get subscription ID

```
try {
    $Endpoint = Get-VstsEndpoint -Name $ConnectedServiceName -Require
    if (!$Endpoint) {
        throw "Endpoint not found..."
    }
    # Get the authentication details
    $subscriptionId=$Endpoint.Data.SubscriptionId
    $tenantId = $Endpoint.Auth.Parameters.TenantId
 ......

} catch {
    Write-Host "Authentication failed: $($_.Exception.Message)..." 
}
```

Part code in task.json (input box to select subscription):

```
 "inputs": [{
        "name": "ConnectedServiceName",
        "type": "connectedService:AzureRM",
        "label": "AzureRM Subscription",
        "defaultValue": "",
        "required": true,
        "helpMarkDown": "Select the AzureRM Subscription that contains the AzureRM App Service"
    },
```

This is [a complete example](https://github.com/AjeetChouksey/vsts-extensions/tree/master/AzureAppSettings/AppKeys), you can refer to it.